# Using vb.net ReadAllBytes

Tags: vb.net

I used vb .NET function ReadAllBytes to read a file and send it over a socket. When received, I used WriteAllBytes. The problem is they are not same size!  The original is 16kb, but the received data is 24kb. My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim bteRead() As Byte

Try
    bteRead = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)

Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
End Try
Return bteRead
```

then i convert bytes to string and send it , and when received i convert it back from string to bytes and do the WriteAllBytes

```
Dim str As String = a(1)
Dim encod As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Dim byteData() As Byte = encod.GetBytes(str)
IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\lol.db", byteData)
```

Comment: I got it :D even before you answer i changed
Dim encod As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Dim byteData() As Byte = encod.GetBytes(str)

by

 Dim byteData() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)

Comment: It could just be different encoding. ASCII takes 1 byte per character, UTF8 can take 2 bytes per character.

Comment: Different encodings? State your answer though - it's useful for anyone who finds this later when researching their own problems...

Comment: It would probably be best to convert your byte array into a base64 string before sending it as text. Or send the bytes directly without using a string at all. Encoding can be a real mess.

Comment: "then i convert bytes to string" that sounds like a bad idea... Send bytes as bytes without conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me was to change:

```
 Dim encod As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding 

Dim byteData() As Byte = encod.GetBytes(str)
```

To

```
Dim byteData() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)
```